# jquery .each within another .each call - How to

Tags: jquery, html-lists, each

I have a html structure like so [list within a list]:

```
<ul class="outer" >
  <li><input type="text" class="outer_name" value="outer_name"></li>
  <ol class="inner">
    <li><input type="text" value="inner1"><input type="checkbox"></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="inner2"><input type="checkbox"></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="inner3"><input type="checkbox"></li>
  </ol>
</ul>
```

And I have multiples of these dumped on the page.
I am trying to specify that for each "outer" element, I would like to alert() something as follows:

```
"outer_name" + "inner1:checked" + "inner2:unchecked" + "inner3:checked"
```

I have been playing around with an embedded .each function but I cant seem to nail it.

Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. `ul` elements cannot directly contain `ol` elements. The [only valid child elements of `ul`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) are `li` elements.

If you fix it:

```
<ul class="outer" >
  <li><input type="text" class="outer_name" value="outer_name">
    <ol class="inner">
      <li><input type="text" value="inner1"><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input type="text" value="inner2"><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input type="text" value="inner3"><input type="checkbox"></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

...then basically:

```
$(".outer > li").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".inner > li").each(function() {
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$(".outer>li")` to make sure only direct children are selected?  Otherwise, you'd select the inner `<li>`s too.

Comment: Thanks! What is a better way to specify this without the invalid-ness;)

Comment: @DJDonaL3000: You have to put the `ol` within an `li`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works:

```
var items = $(".outer .inner li");
var output = "outer_name - ";
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var elem = $("input[type=checkbox]", items[i]);
  if( $(elem).is(":checked") ) output += "" + $(elem).prev().val() + ":checked + ";
  else output += "" + $(elem).prev().val() + ":unchecked + ";
}

alert( output );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that will give you a good start and help see how to use `$.each` within another one
EDIT: fiddle link was incorrect
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fMcSz/2/

```
$('.outer').each(function() {
    var alertMsg = [$(this).find('.outer_name').val()];
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
        var checkText = ' ' + $(this).prev().val() + ': ';
        checkText += (this.checked) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
        alertMsg .push( checkText);

    });
    alert(alertMsg.join(',  '))
});
```